# Input fields not working in Vue with v-model

Tags: vue.js, input, v-model

I have the following template syntax in a Vue single-file component:

```html
<template>
   ...
   <input v-model="newInput">
   ...
</template>
```

In the same component, I have this data:

```html
<script>
   ...
   data: () => {
     return {
      newInput: "",
     }
   }
   ...
</script>
```

Problem: In Chrome, this input field will not accept any text or numbers. The cursor is blinking in the field, but no text is entering. I opened dev tools, and there is no data change when I type. I checked my keyboard settings, nothing weird there.

Appreciate any guidance on this!

Comment: [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tavmqsrp/8/) is the same as yours and it works so there is something wrong with something else.

Comment: I am guessing that you are somewhere else in the code resetting `newInput` to `''`

Comment: @KevinHernandez this was working last week, and I've made no changes. This is also not working for any of the other v-modeled inputs in my app.

Comment: Post a copy link to the entire `.vue` file in your question

Comment: @KevinHernandez I'll figure it out myself. Entire vue file has vuex mutations and axios calls, not posting all that into the question.

Comment: thats why i said post a link to it, link a gist or pastebin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case this work perfectly,

Here in template tag  I've modified input and in the script tag I've modified 'data()' method which accept any text or number.

Try this:

```
<template>

   <input type="text" v-model="newInput">

</template>


<script>

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      newInput: ''
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: You are right, there was no error. After spending hours assessing the issue I determined there was an issue with an evenHandler I was using for the "keydown" action, which prevented the default behavior. Apparently it's a common issue with the keydown event.